# Accessing NSMutableArray elements in SWIFT

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indoor-positioning-system

I am facing a problem with NSMutableArray in swift , I am developing an application using indoor.rs iOS idk to build an indoor navigation application , I want to show all zones on my map and save its names and points. this is my code :

```
 var allZones = [AnyObject]()
    for floor in self._currentBuilding!.floors.allValues as! [IDSFloor] {
        allZones.append(floor.zones as [AnyObject])
    }

    if let zone = allZones[index] as? IDSZone, let points = zone.points as? [IDSZonePoint] {
        points.flatMap { (point) in
            print(point.x)
            print(point.y)
        }

    }
```

and the result is :

```
(
  "<IDSZone: 0x166ede70>",
  "<IDSZone: 0x166edf40>",
  "<IDSZone: 0x166edfe0>",
  "<IDSZone: 0x166ee070>",
  "<IDSZone: 0x166ee0c0>",
  "<IDSZone: 0x166ee130>",
  "<IDSZone: 0x166ee180>",
  "<IDSZone: 0x166ee1c0>",
  "<IDSZone: 0x166ee210>"
)
```

How can i retrieve all zones data , please . This is link for documentation : https://indoors.readme.io/docs/zones-1

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first of all I think you can declare your array:

`let allZones = [IDSZone]` or `let allZones = [AnyObject]`

(let me know if it creates some errors)

then:

```
allZones.appendContentsOf(floor.zones as [AnyObject]) // Swift 2
allZones.append(contentsOf: floor.zones as [AnyObject]) // Swift 3
```

and then you can access to array element like this:

```
allZones.first as? IDSZone
allZones[<your_index>] as? IDSZone
...
```

to get the points:

```
if let zone = allZones[index] as? IDSZone, let points = zone.points as? [IDSZonePoint] {
points.flatMap { (point) in
    print(point.x)
    print(point.y)
}
```

for the name you can use the id if you want.

Comment: It is the same result still can not retrieve data in a correct format

Comment: No , i searched over the idk files i found a file called IDZone has a property property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *points;  when i am trying to print its value i find this :(
    "<IDSZonePoint: 0x165f1630>",
    "<IDSZonePoint: 0x165f16e0>",
    "<IDSZonePoint: 0x165f1700>",
    "<IDSZonePoint: 0x165f1780>"
)

Comment: because it has an interface like that : `code`#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface IDSZonePoint : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger zonepoint_id;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger x;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger y;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger sortOrder;
@end

Comment: @MohammedAboelwafa I updated the answer, let me know if it helps you to get the data

Comment: I updated the code in the question but i have an error : /Users/mac/Documents/Projects/MyFirstIndoorsAppIOS/MyFirstIndoorsAppIOS/ViewController.swift:140:31: Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyObject]' with an index of type '(UnsafePointer<Int8>, Int32) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>'

Comment: @MohammedAboelwafa If you are using an array at row 140, write: self.array? instead of self.array...so add a question mark after your array variable

Comment: I do not use arrays at row 140 , the problem is that the result i get i can not determine it if it string or object or array so that i can not retrieve data

Answer (score 0):

{

```
for floor in _currentBuilding?.floors.allValues as! [IDSFloor] {
        allZones.addObjectsFromArray(floor.zones as [AnyObject])
    }
    let realObject = allZones as NSArray as! [IDSZone]
    for x in 0..<realObject.count {
        let realPoints = NSMutableArray()
        realPoints.addObjectsFromArray(realObject[x].points as [AnyObject])

        let zonePoints = realPoints as NSArray as! [IDSZonePoint]
```

} This is solved it